# Function returns different results

Tags: windows, delphi, encryption

The below function is a basic decryption routine from a legacy application written in Delphi 2007.

```
function TMainFrm.DecodePsw(Passw : String) : String;
var
  i : Integer;
  ss : String;
Begin
  ss := Passw;
  for i:=1 to Length(ss) do begin
    ss[i] := Chr( Ord(ss[i]) - i*21 + 15);
  end;    
  Result := ss;
end;
```

On some client computers it returns a different result with the same input data, what could be the possible causes of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem, one imagines, is that this treats a string as if it were a byte array. But a string's value also depends on an assumed encoding. And since you are using ANSI strings, your byte arrays will be interpreted as though they are encoded in whatever the prevailing locale is. So, the same byte array is interpreted one way on a Windows 1252 locale, another way on a Windows 1251 locale, and so on.

That is why your code behaves differently on different machines. Exactly how you are to resolve your problem I cannot say with the limited information present. I would say that what you have here is not what I would describe as encryption, but I guess you know that. I would also suggest that it is unusual to be decrypting passwords. That is considered bad practise.

Comment: I suspected the locale however after looking in Windows settings i could only find a vague reference for system locale under Region -> Administrative -> Change System Locale... I compared these settings to another computer that is working on the same site and it was identical.

You specifically mention ANSI strings in the above answer, because of Delphi 2007, does that mean this would not be an issue on Unicode?

Comment: Are you sure? This is Delphi 2007 and Chr/Ord are just simple casts. 2007 had no notion of string locales.

Comment: @gabr as byte arrays that's true. But as text displayed on screen say, locale matters

Comment: @donovan the problem you have is that you are working with byte arrays and not respecting encoding and locale. In Unicode you'd encode as utf8 say and crypt that. But why are you decoding passwords anyway?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan There is no particular reason the password is being "decrypted". This is, as i mentioned, a legacy system which is being maintained and I ran across this issue which was new to me and so I though warranted a question. I do thing this particular function requires an immediate review

Comment: @DonovanBoddy are passwords being stored unencrypted? If so, then that's the reason for decrypting.  I think what David is saying is that passwords should be stored encrypted, then you may not have this issue in the first place :)

Comment: @John No  I'm saying passwords should not be stored. Hashes should be stored.

Comment: Unless you are storing a password to log into another system, such as a database server. Then use a proper encryption algorithm, such as AES, with a salt etc